# Enable Firebase Offline in IOS App - no data returned

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my appdelegate I have:

```
import UIKit
import Capacitor
import FacebookCore
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseDatabase

@UIApplicationMain


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) ->
    
    Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

Which is what I assume I need to use for offline - my app launches fine but when I turn off wifi I see no data. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code that actually loads the data and doesn't work when you're offline?